# Strace -- print content instead of address

Tags: linux, file-io, strace

My strace gives me this output

> fcntl64(3, 0xe /* F_??? */, 0xff963a24) = 0

I would like to see something similar to this, where I can see the readalbe content rather than addresses...

> fcntl(3, F_SETLKW, {type=F_WRLCK, whence=SEEK_CUR, start=0, len=0}) =
>   0

Is there an argument I can set?

Answer (score 0):

that output indicates your `strace` is old.  you should upgrade to the latest version -- [4.11 is the latest](https://sourceforge.net/projects/strace/files/strace/4.11/).  if that still fails, please post a report to the [strace mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/strace/mailman/) and we can look at fixing it.

otherwise no, there's no command line flag you can pass to decode a structure and/or flags that `strace` itself doesn't already know about.